# 同じコードでも、一つはエラーが出て、もう一つはエラーが出ないのはなぜですか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**編集前**

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>           
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">       
        <div class="portfolio-caption">           
            <h4 class="aaa"><%= link_to song.title, song %><br></h4>      
        </div>
    </div>
```

この中では使えている`<%= link_to song.title, song %>`のtitleメソッドが

**編集後**

```
<%= link_to ＠songs.title, song %>  ←これを追加するとエラーが出る
<% @songs.each do |song| %>           
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">       
        <div class="portfolio-caption">           
            <h4 class="aaa"><%= link_to song.title, song %><br></h4>      
        </div>
    </div>         
<% end %>
```

このようにすると下記二つのエラーが出るのですが、なぜでしょうか？

```
undefined method `title' for <Song::ActiveRecord_Relation:------>
```

```
titleメソッドが定義されていません
```

---

↓song.controller

```
  class SongsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_song, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  # GET /songs
  # GET /songs.json
  def index
     if params[:user_id]
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @songs = @user.songs.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
     else
      @songs = Song.all.order(:cached_votes_up => :desc)
     end
  end
```

Comment: ＠が全角だからでは？実際のコードは半角の@ですか？

Comment: あぁ、@songsはSong modelのobjectじゃないからですよ。song.titleやってるところでsong.classとやると多分、Songってclassが返って来ると思いますが、@songs.classはSong::ActiveRecord_Relationとか返ってくると思いますよ。

Answer (score 2):

@豚吐露 さんのコメントからのまとめ

1. ＠が全角です。
   ※ そもそも全角なら違うエラーのはずなので、打ち間違いと思われます。
2. `@songs`はSongモデルではなく、Song::ActiveRecord_Relation(SQLの発行結果であるモデルの集合体)です。集合体なので、`title`というメソッドは存在しません。`title`はモデルとして取り出してから使わなくてはなりません。。
   例えると、`['abc', 'cdf'].upcase`としようとしているようなものです。集合体は集合体として扱う必要があって、その中身へメソッドを飛ばしてくれるような忖度はしてくれません。